# django - outputting console to log file

Tags: django

I'm got the following logging config -

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/home/svc_itamapi_dev/itam/logs/debug.log',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

When I hit my api I see the following on the console -

```
[02/Dec/2015 02:27:01] "GET /api/applications/?name=zabbix HTTP/1.1" 200 8232
```

But it's not generating it in my log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've miss understand the use of `django.request`. Based on the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#django-request)

> Log messages related to the handling of requests. 5XX responses are raised as ERROR messages; 4XX responses are raised as WARNING messages.

I think the `django.request` only log info when 5XX or 4XX happened.

You can try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/no/where/` to see if the logger worked.

Comment: you're correct the logger is working.  I'm actually pulling up another project where I have apache setup and the actual URL connections show up in the apache logs so yes, I guess from the logging perspective it's only recording failures not full audits.  Full audits are captured in the apache logs.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `DEBUG=True` in settings.py

`require_debug_true` filter will only pass on records when settings.DEBUG is True.

See [Django Logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/)